A handful of ip addresses at a specific hosting company are not accessible from one location
I am reaching out here to see if anyone has ideas as to what might be happening on our network.
My assumption is that it is a routing issue at our ISP but, since that is a neigh impossible problem to get solved; I am hoping to pick up suggestions that may allow me to resolve our issue ourselves.
Details:

From our office there are a few Ip addresses we cannot access, on of them being the ip address of the external server hosing our own website.
We lost access to the sites while one of the employees was downloading a backup of the sever via FTP.
We can ping the servers either by domain name or IP address without an issue.
Http, Https, Ftp, and SSH all time out when trying to access either by domain name or IP address.
The only networking equipment on the network besides the wifi pods and modem/router provided by out ISP is a single network switch.
We are NOT explicitly blocking the site/ip address on the router/modem. (This is the step that the ISP gets stuck on and cannot move past.)
We have done everything we can to confirm that the hosting company is not blocking our IP address

We have had several calls with the hosting company where they have checked their firewalls to ensure that our address is not blocked
We have a dynamic IP address and our IP addresses has changed several times trying to resolve the issue. So, we are likely not being blocked by an automated rate limiter or anything.


Using something like Cloudflare Warp or a VPN allows access without an issue.
I use the same ISP at home and have no trouble reaching the addresses.


Did you restarted your work router ? as it work from home and it ping from work, possibly a proxy or something in between that didnt worked well after your file transfert

Yes of course, thank you, but that was of course one of our first troubleshooting steps, and we've done that several times since.

Did you have restarted the remote server ?

I think I remember having it rebooted a few weeks ago when this started, but I've asked them to do it again to be certain. Thanks again for the suggestions.\

A simple tool like Ping Plotter will show which hop a TCP connection stops at. Also need to perform a capture on the target host.

The most unsatisfying of answers.
It is fixed, before rebooting the server and before we got to try the Ping Plotter tool the issue was resolved, it had been an issue for several week and now as suddenly as it started it is gone.
Thank you everyone that provided suggestions.
